# Riemann Integration/Sums

Tags: real-analysis

Is the part of the solution I have underlined in green correct? I would have thought the equality would have been the other way round.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are "$S$" and "$s$"?

Comment: @EricTowers Presumably, upper and lower Riemann sum

Comment: @EricTowers This is correct

Answer (score 1):

Informally: The difference between $f$ and $f_+$ is that the latter is flattend to zero where the former is negative. In parts where $f_+$ is zero, the upper and lower sum agree, whereas the upper and lower sum for $f$ itself may differ.

Comment: My strategy is to show that $S(f_+,\Delta) \leq S(f, \Delta)$ and $s(f_+,\Delta) \geq s(f,\Delta) \implies$  the equality is as shown. However $S(f_+,\Delta) \geq S(f, \Delta)$?

Comment: @lemony9201 That strategy does not work. Best you consider single subintervals of the partition $\Delta$.